# How to use CounterFunction to paginate with roman numerals

Tags: notebooks

I want to paginate some pages with roman page numbers. The documentation says it is possible with `CounterFunction[]` - presumably to use with `CounterBox["Page"]` but gives no further hints or examples how to do it. Any help or hint appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
CounterBox["Page", CounterFunction :> FrontEnd`CapitalRomanNumeral]
```

in setting the `PageFooter` option as follows

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
   PageFooters -> {{ None, Cell[TextData[CounterBox["Page", 
       CounterFunction :> FrontEnd`CapitalRomanNumeral]], "Footer", 
           CellMargins -> {{0, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}], None}, 
      {None, Cell[TextData[CounterBox["Page", 
       CounterFunction :> FrontEnd`CapitalRomanNumeral]], "Footer", 
           CellMargins -> {{0, Inherited}, {Inherited, Inherited}}], None}}]
```

This places the page numbers at the center of the footer area. To place the numbers on the right or left change the position of `None`s in the two lists based on:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, use the `Headers and Footers` dialog box

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and also the instructive animation. Because I did headers and footers programatically the last time I haven’t come up with the idea to look in the menu where even a tool tip is shown on the yellow <page> entry to set the option and then via Options[EvaluationNotebook[]] find out how it looks like. Many thanks.

Comment: @Darwin1871, my pleasure. Thank you for the Accept.